# First and a half?

Tags: grammar

"How much did you get?"
"This is my first and a half glass."

Would this be logically correct; meaning that he filled the glass up 1.5 times, and is still in the process of drinking it?

Comment: "Second and a half glass" also sounds kinda weird to me. As well as "forth and a half," "fifth and a half," and so on. For some reason "third and a half glass" sounds all right.

Comment: "First" is ordinal, which is what you want for the beginning of a possible series (and possible hangover). I don't know how you can make "half" ordinal, though. "halfth" is daft. And something like "twelfthth" is even more so, since we use the same construction for most fractions as we do for ordinals, which adds to the confusion. I don't know if you can combine "first" and "half", and think you would need to rephrase the sentence.

Comment: You could say "This is my third half-glass". (There may be an added complication in the sentence, using "glass" as a quantity as well as a receptacle?)

Comment: @MishaRosnach - For me, after the third and a half glass, lots of things sound OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. The first glass is finished. If you fill it again, even halfway, you are  "**having seconds**". (Or, having "a bit of a refill")

Afterwards, you can say that you ***had*** one and a half drinks, but just like the 'half' isn't part of the 'one', it can't be part of the 'first'.

Answer (score 0):

Count your latest glass. If you are still working on it, say "I'm halfway through my second glass."